# Does the mongoDB broker for Celery work by polling?

Tags: mongodb, celery, polling

The [Celery documentation for the mongoDB broker](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/mongodb.html) does not say whether or not it works by polling.  I read in [this blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pub-sub-with-mongodb) that pub/sub is possible with mongoDB, but I don't know if that's what the mongoDB broker for Celery does.

Two sub-questions:

1. if the broker works by polling, what is the frequency and how can I configure it?
2. if the broker works with tailable cursors, is it compatible with sharding (by queue name).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: this suggests that tailable cursors in mongo are broken https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub/issues/15 and their pub sub library currently uses polling too

Answer (score 1):

I took a peek at the source code: Celery is based on [Kombu](https://github.com/celery/kombu), and judging from the mongoDB transport source code (`kombu.transport.mongodb`), the `drain_events` method is simply inherited from the `kombu.transport.virtual.Transport` class, which simply polls every second.

One can override the polling interval by setting the `polling_interval` attribute in the transport options (see [this commit](https://github.com/celery/kombu/commit/9c919e0c95fca7009f3829b1a42d4abae9f970b1)).